# Search on a list for name in c#

Tags: arrays, .net, collections

I've written in C# a code to search on a data file for a name as a reference for information under every name.

This my data file:

```
John  
09076809,45,3rd street, Sudanese,10.11.1979  
Mathew  
05076899,37,3rd street, Japanese ,12.01.1987  
Abrams  
01076033,27,3rd street, Sudanese,22.01.1997
```

Here my code:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private List<Person> peopleList;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeData();
    }

    private void InitializeData()
    {
        // Read data from the text file and populate the peopleList
        peopleList = new List<Person>();

        try
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("people_data.txt");

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i += 6)
            {
                string name = lines[i];
                string[] info = lines[i + 1].Split(',');

                string telephone = info[0].Trim();
                int age = int.Parse(info[1].Trim());
                string address = info[2].Trim();
                string nationality = info[3].Trim();
                DateTime birthday = DateTime.ParseExact(info[4].Trim(), "dd.MM.yyyy", null);

                Person person = new Person(name, telephone, age, address, nationality, birthday);
                peopleList.Add(person);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error reading data from file: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchName = textBox1.Text.Trim();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchName))
        {
            var searchResult = peopleList.Where(person => person.Name.Equals(searchName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();

            if (searchResult.Any())
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = searchResult;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No matching records found.", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name to search.", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, string telephone, int age, string address, string nationality, DateTime birthday)
    {
        Name = name;
        Telephone = telephone;
        Age = age;
        Address = address;
        Nationality = nationality;
        Birthday = birthday;
    }
}
```

When I run the code I received only the first name here `John`.
Let me where is my bug.

Comment: When you checked this with a debugger, what is the *first* line that didn't do what you expected?

Comment: Please learn to avoid using `catch (Exception ex)` - it's a terrible anti-pattern. It swallows up errors and makes debugging hard. You should only ever handle ***specific*** exceptions that you can ***meaningfully*** handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug here:
string name = lines[i];
White spaces should be removed, above line rewritten like here:
string name = lines[i].Trim();

Answer (score 2):

The issue might be with your '+= 6' statement. This is because each person should be represented in two lines (name, information), not six.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i += 2)
{
    string name = lines[i];
    string[] info = lines[i + 1].Split(',');

    string telephone = info[0].Trim();
    int age = int.Parse(info[1].Trim());
    string address = info[2].Trim();
    string nationality = info[3].Trim();
    DateTime birthday = DateTime.ParseExact(info[4].Trim(), "dd.MM.yyyy", null);

    Person person = new Person(name, telephone, age, address, nationality, birthday);
    peopleList.Add(person);
}
```

Comment: You're right should be + =2.but still the problem is persist

Comment: Exactly same error ?

Comment: @hajmanga - That doesn't sound right. Your `+= 6` bug would produce the result that you're getting. Domi has fixed it. The error should have gone away.